# How to test google analytics iOS app installs

Tags: ios, testing, mobile, google-analytics

How can I test google mobile analytics to track iOS app installs without really publishing the app on iTunes?. The only way I find is waiting Apple to release it...

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics provides a campaign troubleshooting guide for iOS 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#troubleshoot

The guide doesn't suggest how to test the app without iTunes but it seems that as long as your app had IDFA enabled and is correctly sending it with hits it should not matter if the app is installed from iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

After integration of google analytics SDK, you can install your app in your phone. In real time section you can see active users and tracking of events, and if integration is ok you should see one active user.Consider that users installs and sessions are showing ofter couple of days in app overview section. Don't forget that:

The Google Analytics SDK for iOS provides a debug mode that will print useful information about what data is being sent to Google Analytics in your logs.

// Enable debug mode.

```
[GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
```